# Alternative to CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS in Android 12 to hide notification tray

Tags: android, android-12

I have an app that carries out a task for the user in the background (using a foreground service).

This has a notification with two action buttons, one of which starts an Activity.

In Android 11, when the user tapped on the action button that starts the Activity, I sent a broadcast using the CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS action, which would dismiss the notification tray so that the user could see the new Activity.

Apps aren't allowed to use the CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS intent action any more, but I don't see any alternative.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#close-system-dialogs

It's a really clunky experience for users to have to press the action button, then close the notification tray manually.

Is there any other way to dismiss the notification tray when the user taps an action button?

Comment: Can you post code for generating such a notification? Closing the notification window is not possible using code on Android 12. But a normal notification wich disappears when creating an activity lets the 'curtain' go up automatically.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Manoj - I have only had this issue intermittently. In most cases, tapping one of the action buttons automatically closes the notification tray on Android 12. During some of my testing that wasn't the case, hence my question.